# Source JAR with Buck's android_prebuilt_aar

Tags: android, buck

I'm adding a dependency on a AAR file and would like to also specify a source JAR so I can browse the sources in a IDE.

With [`prebuilt_jar`](https://buckbuild.com/rule/prebuilt_jar.html) I can specify a `source_jar`.

However [`android_prebuilt_aar`](https://buckbuild.com/rule/android_prebuilt_aar.html) doesn't seem to have this option:

```
android_prebuilt_aar(
  name = 'android-support-v4',
  aar = 'support-v4-22.1.1.aar',
  source_jar = 'support-v4-22.1.1-sources.jar',
  visibility = [
    'PUBLIC',
  ],
)

> TypeError: android_prebuilt_aar() got an unexpected keyword argument 'source_jar'
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an AAR.  Did you mistype the filename there?

Comment: This would be difficult to do since you can have more than one jar in an AAR.  Do you know if the `source.jar` lives in the AAR?  If so, Buck could be taught to check for it.

Comment: @sdwilsh OK I see. There is a separate support-v4-22.1.1-sources.jar.

Comment: Alright, I think you should file an issue against Buck as it doesn't currently support this.

Comment: Thanks for looking @sdwilsh!
Filed an issue, nice to have but not a big blocker: https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/334